# How can we create a parameterized properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties

How can I create a parameterized properties in C#.

```
public readonly string ConnectionString(string ConnectionName)
{
    get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionName].ToString(); }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use a method for this? What you are trying to accomplish looks more like the job of a method.

Comment: indexers are typically used for looking up elements in collection types by a key/index. Hence the name indexers... Your case seems to gravitate towards a new method GetConnectionStringFor("MyConnection")

Comment: No there was no such reason. I just wanted to do it the other way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only type of parameterized property you can create in C# is an [indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
public class MyConnectionStrings
{
    private string GetConnectionString(string connectionName) { ... }

    public string this[string connectionName]
    {
        get { return GetConnectionString(connectionName); }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, just create a method instead - that seems to be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: What is the use of indexer then ?

Comment: @Shantanu: Think of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  To get a specific value, you write `var value = dictionary[key]`.  That's an index property.  It's not much more than a method wrapper, but then again, so are all properties.

Answer (score 0):

C# 4 [allows this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310208%28VS.100%29.aspx), but only to access external COM properties..